# Median of the medians of a list

Tags: python

I need a vector that stores the median values of the medians of the main list "v". I have tried something with the following code but I am only able to write some values in the correct way.

```
v=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
final=[]
nfac=0
for j in range (0,4):
    nfac=j+1
    for k in range (0,nfac):
        if k%2==0:
            final.append(v[10/2**(nfac)-1])
        else:
            final.append(v[9-10/2**(nfac)])
```

The first median in v=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] is 5

Then I want the medians of the remaining sublists [1,2,3,4] and [6,7,8,9,10]. I.e.  2 and 8 respectively. And so on.

The list "final" must be in the following form:

final=[5,2,8,1,3,6,9,4,7,10]

Comment: There is some misunderstanding here. A median is a single descriptive value of a group of values. So your vector `v` only has a single median, which -- by different definitions -- may be 5, 5.5, or 6. 

The thing you suggest as the desired output seems like this questions is related to QuickSort, is that the case? If so, be more specific about what you really try to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Still, I'm unaware of a concept called `second median` and Google didn't show anything reasonable. Could you please give us the definition of `n-th median` you're using?

Comment: I want to do search median of medians from the list

Comment: I'm sorry. By the standard definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median), there there is EXACTLY ONE median per any data sample, so the "medians from the list" is undefined :-( Or perhaps `v` happends to be a list of medians (of some other data)?

Comment: the first median is obtained from the "v" list.
Now the list is divided into 2 smaller ones.
[1,2,3,4] and [6,7,8,9,10]
and now calculate the second and third median

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a note that the task as you defined it is basically equivalent to constructing [a binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) from an array.

Definitely start by defining a helper function for finding the median:

```
def split_by_median(l):
    median_ind = (len(l)-1) // 2
    median = l[median_ind]
    left = l[:median_ind]
    right = l[median_ind+1:] if len(l) > 1 else []
    return median, left, right
```

Following the example you give, you want to process the resulting sublists in a breadth-first manner, so we need a queue to remember the following tasks:

```
from collections import deque   
def construct_heap(v):
    lists_to_process = deque([sorted(v)])
    nodes = []
    while lists_to_process:
        head = lists_to_process.popleft()
        if len(head) == 0:
            continue

        median, left, right = split_by_median(head)
        nodes.append(median)
        lists_to_process.append(left)
        lists_to_process.append(right)

    return nodes
```

So calling the function finally:

```
print(construct_heap([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])) #  [5, 2, 8, 1, 3, 6, 9, 4, 7, 10]
print(construct_heap([5, 1, 2])) #  [2, 1, 5]
print(construct_heap([1, 0, 0.5, -1])) #  [0, -1, 0.5, 1] 
print(construct_heap([])) #  []
```